# Pandas - turn list values (1, 2, 3) into a range (1-3)?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any simple way to take a range of numbers i.e (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and turn them into an easily-readable range (1-5)?

I'm taking IP/port combinations and attempting to list the range of ports seen on a single IP, where I might have 50,000+ ports seen on a single IP but I'd like to be able to see something like [1-50,000] instead of listing out every single one.

```
    IP  Port
0   1.1.1.1     1
1   1.1.1.1     2
2   1.1.1.1     3
3   1.1.1.1     4
4   1.1.1.1     5
5   1.1.1.1     6
6   1.1.1.1     7
7   1.1.1.1     8
8   1.1.1.1     9
9   1.1.1.1    10
10  1.1.1.1    11
11  1.1.1.1    12
12  1.1.1.1    13
13  1.1.1.1    14
14  1.1.1.2    15
15  1.1.1.2    16
16  1.1.1.2    18
17  1.1.1.2    20
18  1.1.1.2    22
19  1.1.1.2    27
20  1.1.1.3    40
21  1.1.1.3    41
22  1.1.1.3    42
23  1.1.1.3    43
24  1.1.1.3    44
25  1.1.1.3    45
26  1.1.1.3    46
27  1.1.1.3    47
```

//code//

```
df.groupby('IP')['Port'].apply(list)
```

//result//

```
1.1.1.1    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]  
1.1.1.2                           [15, 16, 18, 20, 22, 27]  
1.1.1.3                   [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47]
```

//desired result//

```
1.1.1.1                     [1-14]  
1.1.1.2    [15-16, 18, 20, 22, 27]  
1.1.1.3                    [40-47]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
s = df.groupby('IP').Port.diff()
new_df = (df.groupby(['IP', s.ne(1).groupby(df['IP']).cumsum()])
            .Port.agg(['min','max','count'])
            .reset_index('Port', drop=True)
         )
new_df['out'] = np.where(new_df['count']==1, 
                         new_df['min'], 
                         new_df[['min','max']].astype(str).agg('-'.join, axis=1))
new_df.groupby('IP')['out'].apply(list)
```

Output:

```
IP
1.1.1.1                     [1-14]
1.1.1.2    [15-16, 18, 20, 22, 27]
1.1.1.3                    [40-47]
Name: out, dtype: object
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - I'm going to have to do some reading as far as the reason this worked but thank you!!